# create trigger in PosgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

So I found this example:

```
create function eager.account_insert() returns trigger
  security definer
  language plpgsql
as $$
  begin
    insert into eager.account_balances(name) values(new.name);
    return new;
  end;
$$;

create trigger account_insert after insert on accounts
    for each row execute procedure eager.account_insert();
```

The thing I can't understand: function `eager.account_insert()` does not take any arguments, however, it operates with variable `new`. It returns it, but should't it return `trigger`?

Also, this: `insert into eager.account_balances(name)`, this is not some certain record chosen, what it this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `new` (and `old` when it's an update statement) is the `RECORD` you're inserting or updating. You can get columns from it and do whatever you want with them. Many times `BEFORE INSERT` triggers check for valid values etc.

The function must return a `RECORD` with the same columns as the table, or `NULL` if the insert should not happen (usually for `INSTEAD` triggers).

The insert statement is just a regular insert with one column specified of the table and the value is taken from the newly inserted `RECORD`'s column `name`.

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) explains the triggers very well.